# Ethernet Generic Controller

Tags: microcontroller, controller, tcp-ip

I am a Software engineer and I need to make some program (TCP/IP client) that connect to Ethernet with more than one Ethernet controller devices (TCP/IP Server) that control some electrical components (ex: stepper motor)

The program will send an command to that device so it can control a stepper motor for example using TCP/IP protocol

My Question is

Is there any product available on the market like this generic Ethernet controller? or I have to build my own product using Ethernet Microcontroller (ex. pic18 J family) ?

Any recommendation are welcomed, I am not an expert in electronics field?

Comment: There lots of ways to do this.. Depending on how many units you need, how fast you need it and how big can it be? cost?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best off using a generic microcontroller with integrated Ethernet. There are thousands of options here.

For controlling the motor, you want some dedicated logic as well that can create the desired output waveforms without handholding from the main CPU task; otherwise you end up implementing a complex priority system.

So, you should investigate what the motors expect -- some need one pin for direction and one pin toggling for each step, while others require a few outputs to be switched cyclically -- and then look for a microcontroller that can create these waveforms with little programming effort.

Keep in mind that you may also need to handle commands like "emergency stop", so if your controller can handle long sequences on its own, you need a way to interrupt them and find out how far along you were, so you can find out where you are currently positioned.